# Text beginning with “plus” after ragged2e's commands prevents compilation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I lost quite some time due to some weird error (which might possibly stem from a `ragged2e` bug, but I'm note sure so I won't put the blame on anyone), so I thought it would be nice to share this.

The `ragged2e` package defines commands such as `\Centering` that can replace the usual alignment commands and work in interesting contexts such as in a `\pbox`. However, after using `\Centering` dozens of times, I stumbled upon a very particular case that resulted in an error.

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\Centering%
Some random words.

\end{document}
```

However, if the text right after the `\Centering` command starts with “Plus” (non case-sensitive), I get a “Missing number” error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\Centering%
Plus some random words.

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to occur with other commands, such as `\RaggedRight`.

According to what I get with `texdoc`, I'm using `v2.1` of `ragged2e`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting bug. The `\Centering` macro ends with `\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont` whose definition is

```
% ragged2e.sty, line 191:
\newcommand{\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont}{%
  \if@raggedtwoe@spaceskip
    \ifdim\fontdimen\thr@@\font=\z@\relax
      \spaceskip\z@
    \else
      \spaceskip\fontdimen\tw@\font
    \fi
  \else
    \spaceskip\z@
  \fi
  }
```

Since `\spaceskip` is a glue parameter, it will look forward for possible `plus` or `minus` specifications.

Fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Centering
Plus some random words.

\end{document}
```

The appended `\relax` will stop the search for glue specifications.

Comment: you *will* report the bug, won't you?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done.

Comment: Arg. Confirmed; I'll fix this.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that these commands interpret the “plus” as the beginning of a “`plus ⟨length⟩ minus ⟨length⟩`” structure to give stretch values to a length. Adding a `\relax` appears to solve the problem, here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\Centering \relax%
Plus some random words.

\end{document}
```

Leaving an empty line between the command and the text might also work, but it's less compact in my opinion.